# I'm using stitcher class to create a panorama from multiple images. How to reduce calculation time?

Tags: opencv

Is there a possibility to reduce calculation time when stitching more than two images with opencv stitcher class? I noticed that it grows rather exponentially the more images I want to stitch (why?). Is it possible that opencv stitcher tries to stitch every single image with every other image because I got a defined order for stitching my images. So maybe this would be a way to reduce calculation time. I hope you understand what I mean and maybe you can give me some advice to solve my problem.

Comment: Downsampling your images is something to always look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a gpu available?

An easy way to dramatically reduce you processing time is to use GPU when possible. 
Opencv makes it easier every day, and if you look at the doc you'll see that there is a GP flag for the stitcher.

[Here is the doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/opencv_stitching)

You want to play with that element:

> --try_gpu (yes|no) Try to use GPU. The default value is 'no'. All default values are for CPU mode.

Be careful that you need OpenCV to be compiled with GPU support for this to work. You can find more information about GPU support in OPencv [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20GPU%20FAQ#What_GPUs_are_supported.3F).

And if you cannot use GPUs, as @perfanoff said downsampling your image is 99% of the time a good idea in image processing.

Comment: Ok, thank you so far. I tried to use GPU but somehow it didn't work. But I will take a deeper look into this if you say that it might actually help. My images got a resolution of 640*480 so this should be fine as well.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure if I could somehow tell cv::stitcher.stitch function to stitch in the exact same order like my images, it might also help. I think so, because I already tried to stitch images one by one(always add one more image to panorama). This was a lot faster! BUT the result was quiet bad. The panorama was very blurry. Especially on the side were I started to stitch and it got worse the more images I stitched. Stitcher does some kind of image processing that makes the result blurry.

Comment: If you want to go deeper into the stiching method, I think this document is a good start :  http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html#stitching-pipeline. Then I'd have a look at the source code. BTW, you can note that the algorithm first step IS a downsampling already :)

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV Stitcher class matches every input image with all other images, thus an exponential runtime. It is indeed possible to modify the example code provided by OpenCV to match only the first with the second image, the second with the third image and so on. This will result in a more or less linear runtime.

To reduce the rumtime it even further you can reduce the input image size, the kind of features (sift and surf are slow but more robust than others), and the threshold for bundle adjustment.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please point out the code area in the Stitcher class that should be modified to compare only side to side images, instead of one against all? thanks

Comment: "The OpenCV Stitcher class matches every input image with all other images" 

That's n^2 run-time, not exponential.